# Meteor 1.0 - why does "Building the application" take so much longer than it used to?

Tags: meteor

So I just updated to Meteor 1.0. While developing an app locally, whenever I update any of the js files, it takes ~15+ seconds to build the application, during which the console says "Building the application". Erg!

Is this a new behavior in 1.0? It used to take 1-2 seconds to see changes made to js files on localhost (with 0.9.1, I believe, which I think was the last version I had). It was functionally instantaneous. And now there's a huge lag time while developing before seeing changes, which makes rapid code/test iterations take way longer than they used to.

Any way to get around this and make the build process faster while developing locally?

Comment: This is specially annoying when using Velocity!

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Werner pointed out, you are describing the issue #2846 (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2846). They are working hard to getting this fixed to make rapid testing more enjoyable again.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to this fix... Meteor has always been so amazingly fast, but it feels like a totally different beast now. Best of luck to the devs getting this fixed.