# Meteor app takes too long to recompile

Tags: javascript, performance, build, meteor

Are there any flags that can be passed to the `meteor` tool to speed up recompilation? When I make edits to code inside `client/` they get processed almost instantly, while edits in `lib/` or `server/` take tens of seconds to get processed.

I'm guessing it's because the node.js server code is rebuilt and the server is restarted?

Recompilation also (naturally) slows down with increasing code size.

This really slows down development: the `edit -> run -> debug -> edit` cycle takes too long due to slow recompilation.

Are there any magic fixes for this by any chance?

**Edit:** One magic fix seems to be a `meteor reset`, which seems to speed up drastically the rebuild time when `meteor` is relaunched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor 1.0 - why does "Building the application" take so much longer than it used to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878570/meteor-1-0-why-does-building-the-application-take-so-much-longer-than-it-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find that editing files in the `client` folders etc. will update straight away as Meteor knows that you are making client side changes.

Server changes require a complete recompile of the source so it takes longer to run, it also does some re-computation in the packages installed and makes sure there aren't any new or outdated ones, updating if required.

Additionally it monitors the `.meteor/packages` file to see if you have added or removed any packages from there and makes the changes without having to restart the server from the command line.

There was talk of hopefully some speed improvements soon in relation to the solving of package versions but at the moment, while it is clever at packaging versions, it is a bit slow at re-compile time.

Comment: This seems weird to me because I keep getting these _"Downloading packages"_ messages every time I change some non-client code. Is it really going online for things? Should 6,500 lines of my JS code take tens of seconds to compile on an i7 @ 2Ghz w/ 16GB of RAM? Maybe the code that Meteor adds on top of mine adds most of the overhead?

Comment: One year later, this is still a very unpleasant issue to deal with... It is painfully slow to develop a tiny Meteor app on a 4-year old machine under MS Win7. Definitely a no-go?

Comment: [Here's talk about making version checks optional/only when packages file changes](https://forums.meteor.com/t/disable-version-checking-during-build-or-just-do-it-once/12502)

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you'll have to live with it. I have performance issues on reloading and it only gets worst when you application grows.

When you change your code, Meteor simply repacks the whole application. I would to get this fixed, It's very easy to get distracted every you make a change.

Simple solution that you'll hate: I recently bought a better computer and It fells fast but you'll still notice this. On Meteor 0.8.3 this was so frustrating that I wasn't being productive as usual, On Meteor 0.9/1.0 on the new computer It takes adds around 3 to 8 seconds, according to my personal experience.

Comment: Thank you, for now I am throwing more "money" at the problem to see if that fixes it.